# Request.Form[] is not working in Static Method in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, methods, static

I am having one webmethod in aspx.cs page which is Static,I want to use Request.Form[] in that method but is not supported & saying :

Object Reference is Required for the non static field.
How can i use Request.Form[] in that web Method (any alternate way of using)

Regards 
Jeet Nim

Comment: Can you be more specific as to *why* that method needs to be static?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a non-static property in a static context. If your method is static it means it shouldn't depend on the instance being called (here you are using `Request` which is a property of `this` - your page).

If your method does some calculations based on something from your `POST` data then you should add that as a parameter for the method and then you call the method with `Request.Form["something"]` as value:

```
public static int MyStaticMethod(string someParameter)
{
    //logic involving someParameter
    return a value based on the logic above
}

//somewhere in your code-behind
if (MyStaticMethod(Request.Form["something"]) == 0) //something something
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Request.Form` have a meaning if you make post back.

From what I understand you just call the static function on code behind. At that moment the page is not exist, nether you make full post back to fill the Form

> any alternate way of using

The correct way is to send your data, as parameters to the function.

Comment: I just want to access the div id inside that static method ,but problem is that,that div is not having runat=server tag..
How can I access that div id in that webmethod which is static..
Ant other way to do..?

Comment: @JeetNim you can not. What you can do is to return the value you like to add to that div, and add it using javascript. The same if you won to send, get the innerHTML of that div using javascript and send it as parametre to that function.